# What is the meaning of: "When I was in New York, I had visited the Statue of Liberty"?

Tags: meaning, past-tense, simple-past-vs-past-perfect

> 1. When I was in New York, I **visited** the Statue of Liberty.
> 2. When I was in New York, I **had visited** the Statue of Liberty.

- What is the meaning of sentence 2? Is it the same as sentence 1?
- Does it mean that I visited the Statue of Liberty *before* staying in New York? Or is it simply ungrammatical?

---

The answer to my previous [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/389079/is-when-i-lived-in-berlin-i-had-seen-the-movie-three-times-grammatical) suggests that the past perfect with a [when-clause](http://wals.info/chapter/126) referring to a time interval is appropriate in the following:

> My friend asked me about the movie *Spartacus*. When I lived in Berlin, I had seen the movie thrice. So I could tell him that it was very good!

In this example, the time reference is his friend asking about *Spartacus*. The past perfect is used because his seeing the movie (the point of event) is anterior to the point of reference. Here the when-clause only works as a supplement.

In this question, I'd like to ask:

- How is the past perfect interpreted when it is used with a [when-clause](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/clause-phrase-and-sentence/verb-patterns/wh-clauses) referring to a time interval without any other specific time of reference.

More specifically,

- a) Can the past perfect be interpreted as the simple past (i.e. sentence 2 has the same meaning as sentence 1)?
- b) Can the starting point of the interval (the time when I arrived in NY) be interpreted as the point of reference (I visited the Statue of Liberty in my previous stay in NY)?

I've been thinking about these possibilities since I read *5.4 Non-present perfects* in CGEL, which I quoted in my previous question. In it there are two examples:

> ii(a) He **lost** his key while he was running home.
>
> ii(b) He **had lost** his key while he was running home.

And these two are considered to have the same meaning.

Comment: It doesn't sound too good as it is. 2') 'When I visited New York last autumn, I had already visited the Statue of Liberty in the spring, so I gave it a miss.' sounds better.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I know. When a subordinate clause implies a point of time, the past perfect in the main clause means the events experienced by that point of time. My question is what a past perfect in the main clause means when a subordinate clause indicates an interval.

Comment: I'd say it's clumsy-to-ungrammatical here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, is it because there is a more simple sentence, that is sentence 1, which expresses the same idea? CGEL says "they (=non-present perfect) are not subject to the restrictions and specialisation that apply to the present perfect (and which are attributable to the fact that it is in contrast with the simple preterite) ". I'm trying to figure out to what extent they are free from the restrictions. I thought they might lose "anterior time" meaning with an adjunct denoting an interval.

Comment: 'Before I visited New York this year, I had already visited the Statue of Liberty.' is idiomatic. Coupling a when-clause referring to a period rather than a point in time with a past-perfect main clause doesn't work well. // Do you mean 'When I had been in NY, I had visited the SoL'? This is fine, but mixing 'tenses' here isn't.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, what kind of time frame does "when I had been in NY" express ?

Comment: A period prior to the other period / point mentioned.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, then it implies "before the period during which I was in NY". So, the whole sentence essentially means "before I came to NY, I had already visited the Statue of Liberty". Right?

Comment: That sentence is completely ungrammatical when standing alone. If you add another sentence before or after it, you can make it grammatical. But you're probably going to make the whole paragraph rather contrived.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is "When I lived in Berlin, I had seen the movie three times" grammatical?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/389079/is-when-i-lived-in-berlin-i-had-seen-the-movie-three-times-grammatical)

Comment: You can put the visit to the Statue of Liberty in the same time frame as watching Spartacus. For example, you were visiting New York with some friends who wanted to visit the statue.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, I brought back some phrases that I think essential.

Comment: Absolutely fine, it *is* your post after all. I have cast my vote to reopen the question. If later tonight (GMT) you see it is still closed you can make your appeal in [**meta**](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/) asking members to reopen your question. Good luck!

Comment: The reason for the closure is expressed in the banner. Users had already cast their votes to close before you had improved the post. It only needed one vote and that was cast after the edits, which IMO, was a bit unfair and harsh.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, thank you for helping me.

Comment: You've answered your own question in the body.  In your example about _Spartacus_, the time reference justifying the use of the past perfect is in a different sentence. So, using the past perfect in the Statue of Liberty example implies that there is another sentence (before or after) that says what happened later. Without that other sentence, readers get a feeling that you've taken the sentence out of context.

Answer (score 2):

From my reading (I am not a linguist or even a serious student of English), I came to understand that one uses the past perfect **only** when there is something else related in time (that's a clumsy construction compared to your elegant one.) So,

> How is the past perfect interpreted when it is used with a when-clause referring to a time interval without any other specific time of reference.

It's not used in those cases by native English speakers. It sounds like something is missing. It sounds awkward. Without any other specific time referred to, it would be regarded as either a) an unfinished thought or b) the past tense expressed in a slightly awkward manner, or c) an affectation (trying - and failing - to speak in a more ???educated manner) or d) other.

> ii(b) He had lost his key while he was running home.

This is not correct either. It's not a separate time, it's the same time, just a longer time interval. It sounds like an unfinished sentence,

> ii(b) He had lost his key while he was running home...

Better:

> When he went to open the door (<- the separate time), he realized he had lost his keys while he was running home.

That's not awkward. it sounds natural and correct to me, though many people might express it less formally in speech (I speak much less formally than I write.) So, less formally, but less technically "correct",

> Once he got home, he realized he lost his keys.

This is the best answer I can give. The linguists and grammarians can give better answers than I can.

Comment: @Aki it is unfair and improper to ask users to answer questions that are prompted by comments. If anongoodnurse wishes, she can reply in the comments, but  mods (and many in the community) frown on using comments this way.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the two examples from the previous question mean the same thing is because their use would depend on context.

> 1. He felt like running, and he lost his key while he was running home.
> 2. He felt like running, but he had lost his key while he was running home.

In (1), the consistent use of simple past implies that he felt like running, and then went running and lost his key.  In (2), the use of past perfect suggests that he wanted to go running, but he couldn't because he had lost his key *when he was running home earlier*.

In other words, the example phrases by themselves both mean that the key was lost while running home, but whether that action is best described using past simple or past perfect depends on what that action is being compared to.

Similarly, in the New York example, the use of simple past is perfectly acceptable.

> **When I was in New York, I visited the Statue of Liberty.**

You might choose to use past perfect if you were indicating that you had seen the Statue of Liberty earlier than something else that happened in the past:  For example, being shown a picture of the statue.

> She asked me to look at her pictures of the Statue of Liberty, but **I had visited the Statue of Liberty when I was in New York.**

or

> She asked me to look at her pictures of the Statue of Liberty, but **when I was in New York, I had visited the Statue of Liberty.**

As with the case of the keys, in both constructions there is an implication that you saw the Statue of Liberty at the time you were in New York, but the use of past simple or past perfect helps place that action in the context of some other action.

Comment: Then it is what Swan describes as tense simplification.
In PEU, he says "simple past verb forms are used quite often in subordinate clauses instead of present perfect and past perfect, if the meaning is clear." One of the examle sentences there is "He had probably crashed because he had gone to sleep while he was driving.", which is followed by his comment "more natural than "while he had been driving."
So, (iib) is the simplified sentense of "He had lost his key while he had been running home."
What do you think?

Answer (score -4):

When would you use 2)?  Suppose you tell about your visit to New York, and mention two different events during that visit.  Then you could use "had visited" for the first event, and simple past for the second event.

When I was in New York, I had visited the Statue of Liberty before I broke my leg.

Comment: This radically changes the question from the one OP has given.